# I want to know how do the online games (like zynga poker or pool toor live) communicate between 2 users

Tags: multiplayer

From curiosity I want to know how do the online games (like zynga poker or pool toor live) communicate between 2 users...

Do the apps keep pinging the server to check the other player's move or the server sends the browser some dynamic info...

Answer (score 0):

"Do the apps keep pinging the server to check the other player's move or the server sends the browser some dynamic info..."

The turn based games are mostly rely on the pushing (comet)  mechanism.

As soon as server (the Comet also diminished this need to wait ) got the input from one of the player It broadcast to other players; but the desired updating mechanism  can also be achieved via polling in which the server periodically ask the clients.

The same polling procedure can also be implemented by the clients in which they periodically ask the server....

depends on the game need but among one of them the network calls should be considered and preferred way is always the one which involves the least network calls and latency.